# What do spacelike and timelike intervals represent?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, causality

I've understood that with timelike intervals all observers agree on the order of events and with spacelike intervals the order of the events can be changed with the reference frame. However, I wanted to know what these two types of intervals physically/intuitively represent?

So what physical difference separates a spacelike and timelike interval?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449170/37364

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A spacelike interval is where one event is outside the light cone of the other event. No matter how fast you travel ($c$ being the maximum of course), you can never reach or influence this other event.

A timelike interval is where one event is inside the light cone of the other event. You could travel between these two events i.e. there can exist a causality between the two events.

You may want to search the site for other, better and more in-depth, answers to mine. Here's one I found which you might like to read through: [What spacelike, timelike and lightlike spacetime interval really mean?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169631/what-spacelike-timelike-and-lightlike-spacetime-interval-really-mean)