# The physically meaningful form of Minkowski space

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime

I often see the basic form of Minkowski space written as

$r^2 - t^2 = s^2 $   (assume units such that $c=1$)

This does not make as much physical sense to me as writing

$t^2 - r^2 = s^2$

If $r,t,s$ are real numbers then for $s^2$ to be a positive (as the ^2 implies) then $t>r$.
The second way to write this with the - in front of the space term seems the most physically meaningful.

Is there some deeper physics involved I am missing that justifies the time term as negative being the preferred way to write this?

It also just seems natural that writing
$s^2 + r^2 = t^2$ makes the most sense because it guarantees a physically meaningful relationship with $t $ playing the sense of a hypotenuse and always greater than either leg of $r$ or $s$.

Comment: See [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/449194/37364) to [Understanding the difference between timelike and spacelike separations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449170/37364)

Comment: *If $r,t,s$ are real numbers...* This is where you have made an unwarranted assumption; $s$ is not necessarily real. Minkowski space does not have a positive-definite metric, so $s^2$ can be negative.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess my question remains that a physical space composed of points which I can occupy in any meaningful way or matter that I can manipulate will be measured in real numbers. In other words the space-like structure might present itself in the mathematics but we never can occupy space-like points where r>t.

Comment: Yes, we can. At a given time, my head is spacelike-separated from my feet. There is *nothing unphysical* about a spacelike separation. They are simply causally unrelated.

Comment: Ok, I read the posts indicated by mmesser314. If I understand correctly, it does sound as if the most physical way to write this, recognizing time-like points as those physically realizable, is with t>r and s>0. Thank you also to Kindaichi for reformating my question to be more readable.

Comment: *If I understand correctly...* I don’t think you do. You have a serious misconception that spacelike separations are not physically realizable.

Comment: GSmith, you may be right. I at least am reasonably certain that I experience a present that I cannot escape, meaning I exist in the time-like portion of minkowsi spacetime. I have some feeling for the block spacetime interpretation that I think most physicists subscribe to and maybe that gives more "physical reality" to pure space-like points where r>t. Not all physicists agree about the nature of spacetime, so I'll settle for the simple-minded realism that is the reachable present within my little frame, which I can comfortably call physically real.

Comment: In that case, if you go on to study quantum field theory, you’re going to have a very hard time believing that the Feynman propagator, which is related to the probability of a particle moving from point A to point B is spacetime, is nonzero for spacelike separations.

Comment: Hopefully, rather than believing me, you will believe, and accept, Dale’s correct answer. In particular: “it is not correct that $ds^2\ge 0$”.

Comment: *"with $t$ playing the sense of a hypotenuse"* But in the hyperbolic geometry of Minkowski spacetime, $s$ is the hypotenuse, with $r$ and $t$ being the legs of the right angle triangle. That is, the spacetime interval vector can be resolved into a time component of magnitude $t$ and a space component of magnitude $r$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there some deeper physics involved I am missing that justifies the time term as negative being the preferred way to write this?

There is no deeper physics involved. This is merely a convention, and it is not even a very standardized convention. Many people prefer your convention.

Personally, my preferred convention is to use $ds^2=-dt^2+dr^2$ and $d\tau^2=dt^2-dr^2$. So if I am dealing with known timelike intervals I will use $d\tau$, otherwise I will use $ds$.

You are welcome to use either convention, simply indicate which one you pick. But regardless of which convention you choose, it is not correct that $ds^2\ge 0$

Comment: In principle ds² ≥ 0 or ds² ≤ 0 is not an issue for me. I probably asked my question poorly. Maybe to make things more clear in my own mind, can you comment on whether I can experience ds² ≤ 0, and if so can you give me an example. This is more of what I meant by "physically meaningful".

Comment: @OzzieO I don't understand what it means to experience a spacetime interval. Certainly you can physically have an event where a spherical flash of light is emitted. Then there are physical events that are reached by that flash. That set of physical events defines a light cone and (using my preferred convention) the physical events inside that cone have $ds^2<0$ and the physical events outside that cone have $ds^2>0$. So the distinction has a clear physical interpretation: inside vs outside the light cone.

Comment: Maybe meaningless, but I think I live every moment of my life experiencing a spacetime interval and in that interval t > r. It is probably wholly metaphysical, but I have no good reason to think anything other than that apparent realism is physically meaningful. The problem for me may lie in my intuition that treats time and matter as primary and space as an illusion or emergent at best.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is "deep physics" involved. It is that time and space are fundamentally similar. That's where the ambiguity comes from.

For events on the light cone,

$r^2 - (ct)^2 =0 \to c=\frac{r}{t}$

$(ct)^2 - r^2 =0 \to c=\frac{r}{t}$

Consider the unit hyperbola and note the symmetry. The red line is the light cone.The blue line corresponds to the lorentz transformations of $x=1$ and $y=\text{time}=t=0$ for velocities approaching the speed of light. The green line corresponds to the lorentz transformations from $y=\text{time}=t=1$ and $x=0$ for the same increasing velocities. These interpretations could be interchanged.

[image]

Comment: *time and space are fundamentally similar* You always know which dimension is time. Three dimensions appear in the metric with one sign and one dimension appears with the opposite sign. This makes space and time fundamentally *different*.

Comment: @G.Smith ok. but they're still similar in that their axes move together to preserve the speed of light.